# Slowness loading large (2M) images into listWidget

Tags: image, qt, performance

I have a simple QlistWidget where I'm loading images in one call using this code:

```
ui.listWidgetImages->setIconSize(QSize(60, 60));
QStringList::const_iterator i = filenames.constBegin(); // QStringList that holds the images paths
while (i != filenames.constEnd()) {
  QString value = *i;
  QListWidgetItem *standardItemnew = new QListWidgetItem(value, ui.listWidgetImages);
  standardItemnew->setIcon(QIcon(value));    
  ++i;         
}
```

I guess the slowness is the result of scalling down the images to 60/60 size but, is there any way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest soluton would be to pre-generate the thumbnails or use thumbnails already embedded in the image.

If that's not feasible your only option may be to us Qt's [multithreading](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/threads.html). There are two sides to this. To start with the entire task of populating the list could be hived off into a separate thread so that the application doesn't lock during the process. More ambitiously, if the users have multi-core systems you might consider loading and scaling each image in a separate thread.

Comment: what is : "...thumbnails already embedded in the image.."?
and the loading images are random all the time

Comment: Some image formats allow for embedded thumbnail images, particularly TIFF and EXIF (see Wikipedia).

Comment: again this is not an option ,is this is the only way ?